# R test a regression with only statistically significant variables

Tags: r, regression, regularization

I'm performing a multiple logistic regression with a large amount of columns. I want to set all the variables over a certain p value to have 0 coefficients, then test the model on the test data.

Since there's so many variables I'm using, it's impractical to manually go in and set the coefficients. So I'm looking for something like the following.

```r
log_results     <- glm(formula, data, family);
log_results_sig <- get_sig_only(log_results, p value threshold);
```

This way I can use the results with the predict() function, and export the results easily for use in another program.

Additionally, if anyone knows a way to automatically extract the significant variables and refit with them, I would appreciate that too.

Comment: Bad idea. At the least, after eliminating some variables, re-fit the model: the coefficients will change and the model will improve (or not get any worse). Better, review the threads on this site about [tag:model-selection] and search for references to "regularization."

Comment: @whuber I know it's a bad idea. It's something I'm trying to do out of curiosity however. I want to see just how much I lose by doing it this way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9988885/backward-elimination-in-logistic-regression-using-r

Comment: Try to not let curiosity override good statistical practice.